# Could not load the xxx image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier xxx

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9.1

I have created a new iOS project for a sample app and I dragged and dropped a random image in a new image set in Assets.xcassets and left it with the default name "Image" then in my main storyboard in the **generated** ViewController I referenced this image in an ImageView I created and when I run the app in my **Simulator** which is an **Iphone7 plus - IOS 11.1 Simulator** I get this error **instantly**.

```
muzdan[10744:181481] Could not load the "Image" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.example.amr"
```

The name of the image file i added is "small.png" and I did check the target membership in the file inspector on the right. I also tired filling the image set with the right pixels 1x 2x 3x
[image: I did check the target membership in the file inspector on the right]

The Storyboard 
[image: Storyboard]

This problem happened to me in another project so i made this project to check whats wrong and is it from that project or something else and I guess its not from the project. I had everything working till yesterday with the other project and suddenly every image in my project is giving me this error. What could it be can someone help me please ??

**These are my tools** >
Xcode 9.1 -
Swift 4.0

I cleaned the build and the build folder from the product menu and I even tried **resetting** Xcode by these commands

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
rm -rf ~/Libarary/Application\Support/Xcode
rm -rf ~/Libarary/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache
```

and I did reset the simulator content and settings but still the same problem comes back I am hopeless right now I tried every solution in the internet but nothing works.

ps. I did not test the app in a physical device or another Mac because I don't have one

Comment: Can you drag the image to 1x instead of 2x and try ?

Comment: Still the same problem @Sh_Khan

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the storyboard where the image is referenced? Make sure you select the imageView so we can see the attributes.

Comment: I did @robinkunde

Comment: But as sh_khan pointed out, still the images for 1x and 3x are not available??

Comment: @KarthickRamesh i tired to fill the 3 of them  with the right pixels but nothing works .. i had everything working till yesterday

Comment: Whether it's 1x or not doesn't matter, the image is scaled at runtime if the correct scale is not found. I can't see anything wrong with your project. Could you upload the code to Github so I can take a look?

Comment: @robinkunde ok i will and i will update the question .. but still i don't think it's from the project it self .. could it be from xcode 9.1 .. should i reinstall it !?

Comment: You can try but I can't think a reason why that would make a difference. Have you tried deleting the image, and adding it with a different name?
Also, can you check if you're using a case sensitive or case insensitive file system? (Disk Utility will tell you)

Comment: @robinkunde yes tried deleting the image and changing the name in more than one project and still the same problem .. i have even created this new empty project to see whats wrong i add an image named "small.png" to this one as you can see

Comment: Hi everyone @robinkunde I installed Xcode 10.1 and updated my project codebase to swift 4.2.1 , iOS 12.1 and everything seems to work fine .. The problem where in Xcode 9.1 but I don't know how to solve it yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end i installed Xcode 10.1 and updated my project codebase to swift 4.2.1 , iOS 12.1 and everything seems to work fine .. The problem where in Xcode 9.1